# Spring WebFlux, read ServerRequest body, apply some functions and return the result

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am using reactive programming in Spring and trying to do some operation with a POST request. My handler method looks like this:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getDataPOST(ServerRequest request) {
    Mono<Request> requestBodyMono = request.bodyToMono(Request.class);
    Mono<ServerResponse> responseBodyMono =  requestBodyMono.map(requestBodyObj -> {
        Mono<ServerResponse> response = someFunction(); //Returns Mono<ServerResponse>
        return response;
    });
    return responseBodyMono;
}

public Mono<ServerResponse> someFunction() {
    //..Some processing..
    String body = "Some body after processing";
    return ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue(body);
}
```

This is giving me an error as the map is returning `Mono<Mono<ServerResponse>` while I need `Mono<ServerResponse>`. How can I apply my function and return Mono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's right, `.map` returns returns exactly that object you give in `return` clause, but while you are in Mono, it will be wrapped in mono and you are getting `Mono<Mono<Object>>`. But `.flatMap` unwrapping the one level of Mono and you are getting `Mono<Object>` as a result.
Same is true for Stream API but trick works with Stream unwrapping:

```
Stream.of(1,2,3)
.map(i -> Stream::of)
.collect(Collectors.toList()) // List [Stream(1), Stream(2), Stream(3)]

Stream.of(1,2,3)
.flatMap(i -> Stream::of)
.collect(Collectors.toList()) // List [1,2,3]
```

Conclusion: `.flatMap`s unwrap one level of abstraction

Answer (score 1):

It worked after replacing `map` with `flatMap`. If someone can explain why `map` didn't work it will be a lot of help and I will accept that answer.